# An identity about symmetrized matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

This problem comes from a numerical analysis context. Let $A$ be a symmetric, positive definite matrix and let $M^{-1}$ be the inverse of some invertible matrix $M$. One can define the symmetrization $\overline{M}^{-1}$ of $M^{-1}$ by
\begin{equation}
I - \overline{M}^{-1}A = (I - M^{-T}A)(I - M^{-1}A) \tag{1}
\end{equation}
which implies
\begin{equation*}
\overline{M}^{-1} = M^{-T}(M^{T} + M - A)M^{-1} \tag{2}
\end{equation*}
Right now, I would like to prove that
\begin{equation*}
I - \overline{M}^{-1}A = (I - M^{-1}A)^{T}(I - M^{-1}A) \tag{3}
\end{equation*}
After expanding (1) and (3) out, it suffices to show that
\begin{equation*}
(M^{-1}A)^{T}(M^{-1}A - I) = (AM^{-1})^{T}(M^{-1}A - I)
\end{equation*}
I would be quite surprised if that's true because it basically says $M^{-1}$ commute with $A$. Any insights on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Surely the penuiltimate factor should be $(A^TM^{-1})^T$.

Answer (score 1):

Call $N=M^{-1}$. What you want to prove is that if $N$ is an invertible matrix and $A$ is symmetric positive definite, then $$(I-N^\top A)(I-NA)=(I-NA)^\top(I-NA)$$

id est, that $$I-N^\top A-NA+N^\top ANA=I-AN^\top-NA+AN^\top NA\\ AN^\top -N^\top A=AN^\top NA-N^\top ANA$$

Now, if $A$ and $N$ are such that $AN^\top-N^\top A\ne0$, then the identity specialized to $\lambda A$ and $\lambda N$, and to some indexes $h,k$ such that $(AN^\top-N^\top A)_{hk}\ne 0$, becomes $$\lambda^4(AN^\top NA-N^\top ANA)_{hk}-\lambda^2(AN^\top-N^\top A)_{hk}=0$$

which can have at most two non-zero solutions in $\lambda$.

This provides counterexamples to the claim as soon as two non-commuting $N^\top$ and $A$ exist.